# IAR compilation failure, CCS compilation works. Types Incompatibility

Tags: c, types, compiler-errors, arm, iar

After developing a new firmware (main and libraries) with CCS for my CC2538, all errors are debugged, and now, device is working fine.

As from CCS I can not flash the firmware permanently, I'm working with IAR to develop this action.

On IAR, I have created the workspace, the project and included all libraries and files needed to compile the firmware. But, compilation fails due to incompatible types errors.

- Error[Pe144]: a value of type "int" cannot be used to initialize an
  entity of type "signed short *"

  ```
  int16_t *accData[3] = malloc(sizeof(int16_t));
  ```
- Error[Pe513]: a value of type "int" cannot be assigned to an entity
  of type "signed short *"

  ```
  int16_t *accData[3] = malloc(sizeof(int16_t));
  ```
- Error[Pe120]: return value type ("signed short **") does not match
  the function type ("signed short*")

  ```
  int16_t * lsm303d_readAccData(void)
  {
      int16_t *accData[3] = malloc(sizeof(int16_t));
      ...
      return accData;
  }
  ```

**Which is the root cause of these errors?**
Maybe, any option of the compiler? Do I need to add any file? Or prototype on the code?

KR!

Comment: Arrays cannot be assigned to, only initialized. You can do `int16_t *accData[3] = {malloc(sizeof(int16_t))};`, but that's *probably* not what you want...

Comment: you could easily just fix the code errors, which it seems the CCS did not catch (probably because most/all of the compiler warnings were turned `OFF`.   I.E. Fix the code as that is where the problem is, not the compiler.

Comment: @user3629249, of course, I need to fix the code, but how is what I'm asking about. Do you have any tip, please?

Comment: well, we could start by you posting the code then we could see how those 3 lines fit into the overall picture.  Then the 'fix' would be relatively easy to determine.  However, as a first pass, each of those posted lines need the malloc changed to `int16_t *accData = malloc( 3 * sizeof(int16_t) );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which is the root cause of these errors?

"a value of type "int"" is the root cause. There should be no `int` here! Just the `signed short*` (which is your int16_t*) and a `void*` from malloc.

This is because you are using a C90 compiler and forgot to `#include <stdlib.h>`. Upon finding a function with no prototype, C90 would implicitly assume you want a function returning int, which explains the compiler errors "a value of type "int"". But malloc actually returns a `void*`, so this is a severe bug. Solve this by including the header `stdlib.h` where `malloc` is found.

This undesired and irrational behavior of the language was fixed 17 years ago. Consider using a modern compiler instead, or configure your compiler to use the current C language standard (ISO 9899:2011).

That being said, this code doesn't make any sense either:

```
int16_t *accData[3] = malloc(sizeof(int16_t));
```

You probably meant

```
int16_t *accData = malloc( sizeof(int16_t[3]) );
```

Answer (score 1):

The first error is somewhat misleading.  It seems to indicate that you forgot to include `<stdlib.h>`, so `malloc` is undefined and the compiler assumes it returns `int`.

In any case, you are assigning a pointer to an array: this is incorrect.

Returning the address of a local automatic array is incorrect too.

You should define `accData` as a pointer instead of an array, and make it point to an allocated array of `int16_t`.  You seem to want this array to hold `3` elements, otherwise modify the code accordingly:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int16_t *lsm303d_readAccData(void) {
    int16_t *accData = malloc(sizeof(int16_t) * 3);
    ...
    return accData;
}
```

You should configure the compiler to issue more warnings and refuse obsolete constructions such as implicit int.  For `gcc`, add `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` and `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

Comment: This isn't the whole story though. Hint: "a value of type "int"". What int? There is no int here.

Comment: @Lundin: good catch, I updated my answer before reloading the page and seeing your answer.  We are on the same page.